# $\mathcal A$ is empty, what is $\bigcap_{S\in\mathcal A}S$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a collection $\mathcal A$ of sets and a large set $X$. What are 
$\bigcup_{S\in\mathcal A}S$ and $\bigcap_{S\in\mathcal A}S$ ?

The problem is  if $\mathcal A$ is empty, what  do  $\bigcup_{S\in\mathcal A}S$ and $\bigcap_{S\in\mathcal A}S$  mean  ?

Muknres's "topology" page 12,  if $\mathcal A$ is empty, then  $\bigcup_{S\in\mathcal A} S=\emptyset$ and $\bigcap_{S\in\mathcal A}S=X$.

I 'm puzzled about this. Can someone tell me why? Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are probably several other duplicates, some might be more fitting than others. This was the first that came to mind.

Answer (score 1):

False implies true. (All englishmen taller that 4 meters are vegetarian.) For each $A$ in the empty set, is false, so that the intersection is the total set, $X$. By complementarity, you get the other result, but you could have it directly in the same fashion.